# $rootScope.$on event listener function not changing variable values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using $rootScope.$on in a controller to listen to an event emitted by a module I am using (angular-packery). It is working in that it gets the event & I can perform things on the 'args'. But what I want to do is put the args object into an object variable declared outside the scope of the listener function. I cannot get the following code to work:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('searchSpeakersResultsCtrl', searchSpeakersResultsCtrl);

        searchSpeakersResultsCtrl.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope'];
        function searchSpeakersResultsCtrl($rootScope, $scope) {
            var vm = $scope;


            var pckry = {};
            var packeryEventListener = function (event, args) {
                pckry = args;
                console.log(pckry);
            }

            var unbind = $rootScope.$on('packeryInstantiated', packeryEventListener);
            console.log(pckry);
            vm.$on('$destroy', unbind);

        }
})();
```

The console.log within the listener function gives the right value, the console.log outside the function gives the empty object created with var pckry = {};.

However, as would be expected, using the packeryEventListener function directly (not called from $rootScope.$on) does update the value of pckry outside the packeryEventListener function.

What could I be missing? Seems like basic Javascript variable scope stuff is not working when being used with $rootScope.$on . Cheers, H.

Comment: Your problem here is simply one of timing: the `console.log` that sees an empty object is triggered before the callback populates the variable. Remember that angular is a very asynchronous environment: callbacks always happen later than you think.

Comment: Duncan, wow! I wrapped the outside console.log in a timeout & it worked! $timeout(function() {
    console.log(pckry);
   }, 0); So, quick question: what is a good way of working with this? Do I need to wrap all the code outside of the listener function in a timeout, or. . . ?

Comment: or move it into the callback, or read up on promises and start using them everywhere.

Comment: Anyway, that was the solution to my problem. I *knew* it had to be something simple! Many thanks. Make this an answer & I'll give it a big green check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is simply one of timing: the `console.log` that sees an empty object is triggered before the callback populates the variable. Remember that angular is a very asynchronous environment: callbacks always happen later than you think.

Wrapping the code in a `$timeout()` may be sufficient here, but in general you want to be sure the code that uses an asynchronous cannot run until the asynchronous part has completed. That usually means something that starts an asynchronous process should return a promise. With promises you can make something run when they resolve `.then()` or when they are rejected `.catch()` or you can combine them in various ways such as `$q.all()` to wait for several things to complete.

Note that `$timeout` and `$http` also return promises.

Also, once you have a promise, even if it resolved weeks ago you can always use `thePromise.then(function() {...})` as a guard to run some code after the promise has resolved. (And remember even if the promise already resolved the callback is still called asynchronously so not until your other code has returned).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, try to save value in $scope and then see, something like

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('searchSpeakersResultsCtrl', searchSpeakersResultsCtrl);

    searchSpeakersResultsCtrl.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope'];
    function searchSpeakersResultsCtrl($rootScope, $scope) {
        var vm = $scope;


        var pckry = {};
        var packeryEventListener = function (event, args) {
            $scope.pckry = args;
            console.log($scope.pckry);
        }

        var unbind = $rootScope.$on('packeryInstantiated', packeryEventListener);
        console.log($scope.pckry);
        vm.$on('$destroy', unbind);

    }
})();
```

Comment: vm.pckry instead of $scope. but I don't get the use of the vm in the first place. The vm is used when using ControllerAs, then assign vm = this.

Comment: Yes, you don't need to do this as you are just assigning scope to vm, thats it

Comment: About the vm stuff: I'm following the style of a bunch of other code in this app written by some other developers before me, just for consistency at this point as it seems it's not accomplishing anything. Not sure why they did it that way.